# Does process have any overhead in context switching compared to threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

A few words about what I'm planing to do. I need to create some task executor, that will poll tasks from queue and just execute code in this task. And for this I need to implement some interrupt mechanism to enable user to stop this task.

So I see two possible solutions: 1. start a pool of threads and stop them by using `.destroy()` method of a thread. (I will not use any shared objects) 2. Use pool of separated processes and `System.exit()` or kill signal to process. Option 2. looks much safer for me as I can ensure that thread killing will not lead to any concurrency problems. But I'm not sure that it won't produce a big overhead.

Also I'm not sure about JVM, if I will use separated processes, each process will be using the separated JVM, and it can bring a lot of overhead. Or not. So my question in this. Choosing a different language without runtime for worker process is possible option for me, but I still don't have enough experience with processes and don't know about overhead.

Comment: Processes are more overhead to start up, and the way you communicate with them is different than threads.  Switching between processes vs. switching between threads?  One way you can find out for sure is to *measure;* stand up a bunch of processes and stand up a bunch of threads, and see which one seems more suitable for your specific use case.  There's no "right" answer here, because it's going to depend on many factors specific to your particular use case.

Comment: Re, "I will not use any shared objects." You might not write any code that creates and uses shared objects, but Java code is very dependent on run-time support from the Java standard library and, from the JRE. How can you know whether  or not your threads use shared objects when they are executing library and JRE code that you did not write? If you can't guarantee that it doesn't happen, then you should not kill threads.

Answer (score 3):

> start a pool of threads and stop them by using .destroy() method of a thread. (I will not use any shared objects)

You can't stop threads on modern VMs unless said thread is 'in on it'. destroy and friends do not actually do what you want and this is unsafe. The right way is to call `interrupt()`. If the thread wants to annoy you and not actually stop in the face of an interrupt call, they can. The solution is to fix the code so that it doesn't do that anymore. Note that raising the interrupt flag will guaranteed stop any method that is sleeping which is specced to throw InterruptedException (sleep, wait, etc), and on most OSes, will also cause any I/O call that is currently frozen to exit by throwing an IOException, but there is no guarantee for this.

> 2. Use pool of separated processes and System.exit() or kill signal to process.

Hella expensive; a VM is not a light thing to spin up; it'll have its own copy of all the classes (even something as simple as `java.lang.String` and company). 10 VMs is a stretch. Whereas 1000 threads is no problem.

> And for this I need to implement some interrupt mechanism to enable user to stop this task.

The real problem is that this is very difficult to *guarantee*. But if you control the code that needs interrupting, then usually no big deal. Just use the interrupt() mechanism.

EDIT: In case you're wondering how to do the interrupt thing: Raising the interrupt flag on a thread just raises the flag; nothing else happens unless you write code that interacts with it, or call a method that does.

There are 3 main interactions:

1. All things that block and are declared to throw InterruptedEx will lower the flag and throw InterruptedEx. If the flag is up and you call `Thread.sleep`, that will *immediately*_ clear the flag and throw that exception without ever even waiting. Thus, catch that exception, and return/abort/break off the task.
2. `Thread.interrupted()` will lower the flag and return true (thus, does so only once). Put this in your event loops. It's not `public void run() {while (true) { ... }}` or `while (running) {}` or whatnot, it's `while (!Thread.interrupted()` or possibly `while (running && !Thread.interrupted9))`.
3. Any other blocking method may or may not; java intentionally doesn't specify either way because it depends on OS and architecture. If they do (and many do), they can't throw interruptedex, as e.g. `FileInputStream.read` isn't specced to throw it. They throw IOException with a message indicating an abort happened.

Ensure that these 3 code paths one way or another lead to a task that swiftly ends, and you have what you want: user-interruptible tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I know about interrupt method and the reasons, why I should prefer this over other options. But it doesn't fit my needs, because I have no guarantees about what code will be inside.

Comment: @Uraty you shouldn't be running code you don't trust. VMs is the answer, perhaps, but you're signing up for a 100x+ cost.

Answer (score 0):

## Executors framework

Java already provides a facility with your desired features, the *Executors* framework.

You said:

> I need to create some task executor, that will poll tasks from queue and just execute code in this task.

The `ExecutorService` interface does just that.

Choose an implementation meeting your needs from the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class. For example, if you want to run your tasks in the sequence of their submission, use a single-threaded executor service. You have several others to choose from if you want other behavior.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
```

You said:

> 1. start a pool of threads

The executor service may be backed by a pool of threads.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​( 3 ) ;  // Create a pool of exactly three threads to be used for any number of submitted tasks.
```

You said:

> just execute code in this task

Define your task as a class implementing either [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or `Callable`. That means your class carries a `run` method, or a `call` method.

```java
Runnable task = ( ) -> System.out.println( "Doing this work on a background thread. " + Instant.now() );
```

You said:

> will poll tasks from queue

Submit your tasks to be run. You can submit many tasks, either of the same class or of different classes. The executor service maintains a queue of submitted tasks.

```java
executorService.submit( task );
```

Optionally, you may capture the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object returned.

```java
Future future = executorService.submit( task );
```

That `Future` object lets you check to see if the task [has finished](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) or [has been cancelled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isCancelled()).

```java
if( future.isDone() ) { … }
```

You said:

> enable user to stop this task

If you want to cancel the task, call [`Future::cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)).

- Pass `true` if you want to interrupt the task if it has already begun execution.
- Pass `false` if you only want to cancel the task before it has begun execution.

```java
future.cancel( true );
```

You said:

> looks much safer for me as I can ensure that thread killing will not lead to any concurrency problems.

Using the Executors framework, you would not be creating or killing any threads. The executor service implementation handles the threads. Your code never addresses the `Thread` class directly.

So no concurrency problems of that kind.

But you may have other concurrency problems if you share any resources across threads. I highly recommend reading [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice) by Brian Goetz et al.

You said:

> But I'm not sure that it won't produce a big overhead.

As the correct [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255526/642706) explained, your approach would certainly create *much* more overhead that would the use of the Executors framework.

FYI, in the future [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) will bring virtual threads (fibers) to the Java platform. This will generally make background threading even faster, and will make practical having many thousands or even millions of non-CPU-bound tasks. Special builds available now on early-access Java 16.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = newVirtualThreadExecutor() ; 
executorService.submit( task ) ;
```

Comment: Hah, thanks ) I not accidentally used terminology that is really close to ExecutorService - because it does exactly what I need and I'm familiar with this enough. But, if you look in source code of ExecutorService, you can find, that submit returns "FutureTask" and there in implementation of "cancel" method, it calls "interrupt" on thread. But "interrupt" doesn't actually stop a thread, but rather sets "interrupted" flag, so there is no guaranties that it actually will be interrupted. And it's actually a problem.